# Local Task Menu - Add a Page link

Tags: panels, routes

I am trying to figure out the best way to add a panel page navigation item to the local task menu set.

I want to create a Panel Page with QuickTabs to build a simple UX for a non-drupal admin to updated and edit users for there events.

I can add the quick tabs etc. to the panel page, however, I am not sure how to add the menu item to the local task menu tabs.

So, when you edit an event here is what I want the menu to look like...

View | Edit | **Panel Page**

So, **Panel Page**  is the new local task menu item for my panel page. I have been searching for a way and change not find it.

Answer (score 0):

So, it took a while to figure what I needed was to add a custom local task navigation tab. To handle adding local task you need to learn the hook_menu() function, right after you learn to build your first [hello world module](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360). P.S. having the Test 1 and 2 menu items is what tells Drupal to create the outcomes tab.

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function outcomes_menu() {
  $items['node/%node/outcomes'] = array(
        'title' => 'Outcomes',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  $items['node/%node/outcomes/test1'] = array(
        'title' => 'Outcomes Test1',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'=>array('drupalform_form1')
  );
  $items['node/%node/outcomes/test2'] = array(
        'title' => 'Outcomes Test2',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments'=>array('drupalform_form1')
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Hopefully, this helps someone else.